# C++: Base class calling own virtual function - an anti-pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, c++14

I see pattern like below commonly used. We have a base class which does most of the work, but calls one of its own virtual/pure-virtual function to do the part of the job which is different for each derived type. A contrived example:

```
struct PacketProcessor {
    virtual void parseEncap(pkt) = 0;
    void process(Pkt pkt)
    {
        parseEncap(pkt);  // Calls its own virtual function to parse the encap
        processFurther(pkt);
        ...
    }
};
```

We create derived classes which will override the virtual functions and provide functionality specific to derived classes.

```
struct EthernetProcessor : public PacketProcessor {
    void parseEncap(Pkt) override { // parse ethernet encap}
};

struct PPPProcessor : public PacketProcessor {
     void parseEncap(Pkt) override { //parse ppp encap }
};
```

But I feel with this sort of pattern, as time goes on, more and more functions in the base class gets virtualized or more virtual function added and called at random places to make room for different derived class behavior.

[In a real life code I have see an add() and add_extra() virtual functions :-) ]

And over time the code does not have a solid structure any more as each type is handled in totally different ways. Even though the common base class sort of gives a false notion a structure. But yes it still keeps code for different types segregated as opposed to if (type1)/else(type2).

Another way of achieving something similar is to abstract out the differences into a different class (hierarchy) and call the virtual functions in that. This is also very common For Eg:

```
struct Encap {
    virtual void parseEncap(Pkt) = 0;
};

struct EthernetEncap : public Encap {
    void parseEncap(Pkt pkt) {}
};

struct PPPEncap : public Encap {
    void parseEncap(Pkt pkt) {}
};

struct PacketProcessor {
    PacketProcessor(Encap *encap) : m_encap{encap} {}
    void process(Pkt pkt)
    {
       m_encap->parseEncap(pkt);
       processFurther(pkt);
       ...
    }
private:
    EncapPtr m_encap;
};
```

But in this case also there can be frivolous functions added the Encap class. Or there will too many component classes like the Encap providing different functionality.

But the good thing is that the PacketProcessor will follow a specific path for all types of Encaps. Also this approach is not as flexible as the former pattern because we need to put all 'Encap's into a very specific mold.

So my question is:

Is either one of these an anti-pattern and should avoided or drawbacks simply lack of discipline and nothing to do with the pattern followed.

Comment: Is this actually working for you?  Virtual dispatch doesn't work in constructors so you never call the derived class function, just the bases.

Comment: fwiw what you have in the first snippet is basically the gang of fours "template method pattern" ( appearance of "template" in the name is a little unfortunate and has nothing to do with c++ templates)

Comment: I would not call it an anti-pattern, it is what is called `template method`. Usability in your local project may vary, of course.

Comment: pattern might be misused, but it is not wrong by itself.

Comment: I would not call them an anti-pattern.  But (as with many facilities provided by any given language) they are things that can be abused or misused.

Comment: That's kind of how virtual functions are work. Virtual functions are designed to get overridden. There is nothing wrong with that, it's simply a design choice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the name of the pattern so that I could read a bit more about it. I think my question, inadvertently, boils down to Template Method Pattern vs Dependency Injection(probably).

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is called [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

> But I feel with this sort of pattern, as time goes on, more and more
>   functions in the base class gets virtualized or more virtual function
>   added and called at random places to make room for different derived
>   class behavior.

The pattern is often applied within frameworks where the base class is provided by the framework and then the actual functionality is provided by users of the framework. In this case the base classes are rather stable while the number of users and the variability of the implementations is huge. In that scenario the pattern does a good job.

Your situation seems to be a little different as I understand that you are in control of both, the base class and the implementations. If this is true, then maybe the template method pattern is not what you really need.

> Is either one of these an anti-pattern and should avoided or drawbacks
>   simply lack of discipline and nothing to do with the pattern followed.

To be plain honest I didnt completely understand your alternative approach. However, I cannot see anything fundamentally broken on it. However, consider that in case the base and derived are not both under your control, your approach is very different from the template method approach.

Any pattern can be misused and overused. Moreover, no pattern comes without alternative. The main benefit of patterns is nothing more than that they are patterns. They can be recognized. Your first snippet has been recognized as the template method pattern by several users, while the second, really no offense, is just another class hierarchy.

**TL;DR** Patterns are not the holy grail. Just because a pattern can be misused does not imply that the pattern is broken. If you think a variation or something completely different works better for you then go ahead.

Comment: Second seems to be an example of Dependency injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: @David oh right, already before I thought the answer could be improved by comparing the two approaches in a better way. I think I will edit later. Thanks for the link